# Deleta a row with 'del' command in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Upon reading [pandas.dataframe.drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html),

a column could be removed by drop or del

```
#+begin_src ipython :session alinbx :results output
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4),
                  columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
print(df, '\n'+'--'*50)
# Drop columns
print(df.drop(['B', 'C'], axis=1), '\n'+'--'*50)
del df['A']
# Drop a row by index
print(df.drop([0, 1]), '\n'+'--'*50)
print(df.drop([0, 1], axis=0))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example
   A  B   C   D
0  0  1   2   3
1  4  5   6   7
2  8  9  10  11 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   A   D
0  0   3
1  4   7
2  8  11 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   B   C   D
2  9  10  11 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   B   C   D
2  9  10  11
#+end_example
```

When try to delete a rwo with del, it report error

```
#+begin_src ipython :session alinbx :results output
del df.iloc[0, :]
#+end_src

AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-4fdbabf9cb4f> in <module>
----> 1 del df.iloc[0, :]

AttributeError: __delitem__
```

How could delete a row with 'del`

Comment: Is there a particular reason you must use `del`? `df.drop(index=0)` would work fine too.  In any case, I believe `.iloc` and `.loc` returns a *copy* of the item, so deleting the copy is meaningless even if it works.

Comment: A hack would be transposing the dataframe and then deleting the row which is now a column.

Comment: @MichaelGardner it would still be a copy of the `df`, unless you do three `inplace` operation... which seems silly when one `drop` would do.

Comment: "*I believe .iloc and .loc return a copy of the item*", they return a new DataFrame (not a copy), but the values within the container are still references (if you update one, the other is updated too)

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove a row with `del` as rows returned by `.loc` or `.iloc` are *copies* of the DataFrame, so deleting them would have no effect to your actual data.

Observe:

```
>>> df['A'] is df['A']
True
>>> df.loc[0] is df.loc[0]
False
>>> df.iloc[0, :] is df.loc[0, :]
False
```

`del df['A']` works because it is using `__getitem__` to retrieve the actual object, so by removing the key `'A'` it will also remove the associated column data of the frame.

To remove rows, you would want to `df.drop(index=0)` or `df.drop([0], axis=0)` instead.  To delete multiple rows, `df.drop(index=range(...))` would also work, assuming your indices are `int`s.